# Conditional covariance of two independent normal variables when their sum is fixed

Tags: probability, statistics, causality

I am reading through [Brady Neal's "Introduction to Causality"](https://www.bradyneal.com/Introduction_to_Causal_Inference-Dec17_2020-Neal.pdf) course textbook and have got to Section 3.6 where Berkson's paradox is discussed. Neal provides the following toy example:

$$
X_{1} = \mathcal{N}(0,1) \\ 
X_{3} = \mathcal{N}(0,1) \\
X_{2} = X_{1} + X_{3}
$$

He then proceeds to compute the covariance of $X_{1}$ and $X_{3}$ as a sanity check:

$$
\text{Cov}(X_{1}, X_{3}) = \mathbb{E}[X_{1}X_{3}] - \mathbb{E}[X_{1}]\mathbb{E}[X_{3}] = 
\mathbb{E}[X_{1}X_{3}] = \mathbb{E}[X_{1}]\mathbb{E}[X_{3}] = 0
$$

where we used independence. Next Neal computes the conditional covariance given that $X_{2} = x$.

$$
\text{Cov}(X_{1}, X_{3} \,|\, X_{2} = x) = \mathbb{E}[X_{1}X_{3} \,|\, X_{2} = x] = 
\mathbb{E}[X_{1}(x  - X_{1})] = x\mathbb{E}[X_{1}] - \mathbb{E}[X^{2}_{1}] = -1
$$

**Is this correct?**

When I do my own calculation I seem to get the following result:

$$
\text{Cov}(X_{1}, X_{3} \,|\, X_{2} = x) = \mathbb{E}[X_{1}X_{3}\,|\, X_{2} = x] - \mathbb{E}[X_{1} \,|\,X_{2}=x]\mathbb{E}[X_{3}\,|\,X_{2}=x]
$$

Consider each factor separately in the second term:

$$
\mathbb{E}[X_{1} \,|\, X_{2} = x] = \mathbb{E}[X_{1} \,|\, X_{1} + X_{3} = x] =
\mathbb{E}[x - X_{3}] = x - \mathbb{E}[X_{3}]
$$

Likewise we have

$$
\mathbb{E}[X_{3} \,|\, X_{2} = x] = x - \mathbb{E}[X_{1}]
$$

Multiplying both terms we have:

$$
\mathbb{E}[X_{1} \,|\,X_{2}=x]\mathbb{E}[X_{3}\,|\,X_{2}=x] = (x - \mathbb{E}[X_{3}])(x - \mathbb{E}[X_{1}]) = x^{2}
$$

Now consider the first term:

$$
\mathbb{E}[X_{1}X_{3}\,|\, X_{2} = x] = \mathbb{E}[X_{1}X_{3}\,|\, X_{2} = x] =
\mathbb{E}[X_{1}X_{3}\,|\, X_{1} + X_{3} = x] = \\
\mathbb{E}[X_{1}(x - X_{1})] =
x\mathbb{E}[X_{1}] - \mathbb{E}[X_{1}^{2}] = 0 - 1 = -1
$$

Putting everything together we have:

$$
\text{Cov}(X_{1}, X_{3} \,|\, X_{2} = x) = \mathbb{E}[X_{1}X_{3}\,|\, X_{2} = x] - \mathbb{E}[X_{1} \,|\,X_{2}=x]\mathbb{E}[X_{3}\,|\,X_{2}=x] = -1 - x^{2}
$$

**Am I doing something wrong?** I am concerned the author is forgetting that the expectations in the second term are conditional leading them to set the second term to zero as in the unconditioned case. I may also be using the wrong definition for conditional covariance, although no explicit definition is provided in the book.

Note that this example is an attempt to model a collider where $X_{1}$ and $X_{3}$ are parents of $X_{2}$.

EDIT: **Both myself and the textbook are wrong!**

Thanks to Henry for pointing this out, whose answer I have accepted below. I thought I would correct my approach using Henry's working to highlight my errors.

As before we have:

$$
\text{Cov}(X_{1}, X_{3} \,|\, X_{2} = x) = \mathbb{E}[X_{1}X_{3}\,|\, X_{2} = x] - \mathbb{E}[X_{1} \,|\,X_{2}=x]\mathbb{E}[X_{3}\,|\,X_{2}=x]
$$

Let's deal with the second term first. Clearly we have:

$$
\mathbb{E}[X_{1} \,|\,X_{2}=x]\mathbb{E}[X_{1}\,|\,X_{2}=x] = 
\mathbb{E}[X_{1}\,|\,X_{2}=x]^{2}
$$

Applying the first formula derived by Henry in this [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9071/intuitive-explanation-of-contribution-to-sum-of-two-normally-distributed-random) we have

$$
\mathbb{E}[X_{1}\,|\,X_{2}=x]^{2} = \frac{x^{2}}{4}
$$

Now for the first term we have

$$
\mathbb{E}[X_{1}X_{3}\,|\, X_{2} = x] = \mathbb{E}[(x-X_{3})X_{3}\,|\, X_{2} = x] = x\mathbb{E}[X_{3}\,|\, X_{2} = x] - \mathbb{E}[X_{3}^{2}\,|\, X_{2} = x]
$$

Note how the conditional in the expectation remains as $X_{3}$ is still conditioned on $X_{2}$. This is what caused the issue with my analysis! Following a similar logic as above with $X_{3}$ in place of $X_{1}$ we have:

$$
\mathbb{E}[X_{1}X_{3}\,|\, X_{2} = x] = \frac{x^{2}}{2} - \mathbb{E}[X_{3}^{2}\,|\, X_{2} = x]
$$

Adding and subtracting $\mathbb{E}[X_{3}\,|\,X_{2} = x]^{2}$ we have

$$
\mathbb{E}[X_{1}X_{3}\,|\, X_{2} = x] = \frac{x^{2}}{2} - (\mathbb{E}[X_{3}^{2}\,|\, X_{2} = x] - \mathbb{E}[X_{3}\,|\,X_{2} = x]^{2}) - \mathbb{E}[X_{3}\,|\,X_{2} = x]^{2}
$$

Observe that the term in the brackets is simply the conditional variance of $X_{3}$. Hence, using the second identity provided by Henry in the aforementioned [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9071/intuitive-explanation-of-contribution-to-sum-of-two-normally-distributed-random) we have:

$$
\mathbb{E}[X_{1}X_{3}\,|\, X_{2} = x] = \frac{x^{2}}{2} - \frac{1}{2} - \mathbb{E}[X_{3}\,|\,X_{2} = x]^{2}
$$

Recall that we calculated the leftover term (with $X_{1}$ in place of $X_{3}$. Plugging in our solution we have:

$$
\mathbb{E}[X_{1}X_{3}\,|\, X_{2} = x] = \frac{x^{2}}{2} - \frac{1}{2} - \frac{x^{2}}{4} = \frac{x^{2}}{2} - 1/2
$$

Putting everything together we end up with:

$$
\text{Cov}(X_{1}, X_{3} \,|\, X_{2} = x) = \mathbb{E}[X_{1}X_{3}\,|\, X_{2} = x] - \mathbb{E}[X_{1} \,|\,X_{2}=x]\mathbb{E}[X_{3}\,|\,X_{2}=x] \\ = \frac{x^{2}}{2} - 1/2 - \frac{x^{2}}{4} = -1/2
$$

Finally, we arrive at the correct result! Note that I have left some details out regarding how the conditional expectations and variances used from Henry's [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9071/intuitive-explanation-of-contribution-to-sum-of-two-normally-distributed-random) are calculated. Although, I believe a question which presents the working for a similar problem is linked there. I may add these derivations later but for now I am happy to assume that Henry is a divine oracle capable of correctly computing the conditional moments of normal distributions :).

Comment: The author is making a mistake. The conditioning on $X_2=x$ cannot be dropped.

Comment: @geetha290krm Thanks that's what I expected, I will shoot them an email.

Comment: Theory and simulation both suggest a constant conditional covariance close to $-\frac12$

Comment: @Henry could you elaborate further on this? What theory are you referring to and which experiments did you run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conditioned on $X_1+X_3=x$,  $X_1$ has a conditional distribution which is $N(\frac x2, \frac12)$.  So too does $X_3$.  [This stats.stackexchange gives a more general version](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9071/intuitive-explanation-of-contribution-to-sum-of-two-normally-distributed-random)

So each of their conditional variances is $\frac12$ and their conditional covariance is then $-\frac12$. This does not vary with $x$.

Here is a simulation in R illustrating this, conditioning on cases close to $x$ values from $-2$ to $2$

```
set.seed(2022)
cases <- 10^6
X1 <- rnorm(cases)
X3 <- rnorm(cases)
X2 <- X1 + X3
condcovars <- numeric(41)
for (i in (-20):20){
 close <- X2 > i/10 - 1/20 & X2 < i/10 + 1/20
 condcovars[i+21] <- cov(X1[close], X3[close])
 }
names(condcovars) <-  (-20:20)/10
condcovars

#         -2       -1.9       -1.8       -1.7       -1.6       -1.5       -1.4 
# -0.5042118 -0.4943630 -0.5069618 -0.4920338 -0.5013615 -0.4952248 -0.4984781 
#       -1.3       -1.2       -1.1         -1       -0.9       -0.8       -0.7 
# -0.4946318 -0.5015043 -0.4978977 -0.5051132 -0.5016172 -0.4964760 -0.4979527 
#       -0.6       -0.5       -0.4       -0.3       -0.2       -0.1          0 
# -0.4991278 -0.5020100 -0.5010565 -0.4961058 -0.4952697 -0.5034277 -0.4959253 
#        0.1        0.2        0.3        0.4        0.5        0.6        0.7 
# -0.5054419 -0.4998629 -0.5007847 -0.4957954 -0.4983496 -0.5031784 -0.5067993 
#        0.8        0.9          1        1.1        1.2        1.3        1.4 
# -0.5063600 -0.4913827 -0.5006796 -0.4986025 -0.4936689 -0.4922959 -0.5081856 
#        1.5        1.6        1.7        1.8        1.9          2 
# -0.4911572 -0.4945096 -0.5052851 -0.4933594 -0.4996732 -0.5070671 

plot((-20:20)/10, condcovars , ylim=c(-1,0))
```

[image]

Comment: How do you conclude the conditional covariance is a -1/2, theoretically speaking?

Comment: @NickBishop $\text{Cov}(X_{1}, X_{3} \mid X_{1}+X_3 = x)$ $=\text{Cov}(X_{1}+ X_{3},X_3 \mid X_{1}+X_3 = x)+\text{Cov}(-X_{3},X_{3} \mid X_{1}+X_3 = x)$ $=0-\text{Var}(X_{3}\mid X_{1}+X_3 = x)  $  and $\text{Var}(X_{3}\mid X_{1}+X_3 = x) = \frac{\text{Var}(X_{1})\text{Var}(X_{3})}{\text{Var}(X_{1})+\text{Var}(X_{3})}$

Comment: Thanks, so where d you think the error in the analysis is? I am guessing I am missing something or making an incorrect derivation.

Comment: @NickBishop One example is $E[X_1 \mid X_1+X_3=x]$ which should clearly be $\frac x2$ not $x$ and so $E[X_1 \mid X_1+x_3=x]E[X_3 \mid X_1+x_3=x]= \frac{x^2}{4}$ not $x$

Comment: So I guess the fundamental problem is the step from $\mathbb{E}[X_{1}\,|\, X_{1} + X_{3} = x]$ to $\mathbb{E}[x - X_{3}]$. $X_{3}$ is also conditioned on $X_{2} = x$. So I can't do this because I am replacing one conditioned random variable with another one with exactly the same condition.

Comment: @NickBishop - that sort of thing: though here you have exchangeability and identical conditional distributions which may help